# How to add Scheduling in a Sandboxed app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I need to add scheduling to my app. So that my app will launch automatically at a specified time and date. I have done it by referring [Scheduling Timed Jobs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-CH1-SW2). I have placed the plist file for scheduling in `/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents`. It works well in the non-sandboxed app, but it is not working in a sandboxed app. I can't able to add the scheduling file to the path `/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents`. It gives me the error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“com.sample.schedule.plist” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “LaunchAgents”." UserInfo=0x100114f10 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SchedulingInSandbox-cernhnigkuqhehbndryxlekpiiiu/Build/Products/Debug/SchedulingInSandbox.app/Contents/Resources/com.sample.schedule.plist, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/com.sample.schedule.plist, NSFilePath=/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SchedulingInSandbox-cernhnigkuqhehbndryxlekpiiiu/Build/Products/Debug/SchedulingInSandbox.app/Contents/Resources/com.sample.schedule.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0x1001132d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

I have added the LaunchAgents Path in Entitlements too.

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
<array>
    <string>/Library/LaunchAgents/</string>
</array>
```

But still I can't able to add the scheculing plist in LaunchAgents Directory. Whether I am doing correctly or there is another way for the doing the scheduling in sandboxed app.

**EDIT 1:**
If I manually create the folder in `/Library/Containers/LaunchAgents` and put the plist there I am getting this error:

```
Could not open job overrides database at: /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist: 1: Operation not permitted
launch_msg(): Socket is not connected
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your job plist into

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/<my app identifier>/Data/Library/LaunchAgents/<my app identifier>.<somename>.plist
```

This would be the data container for your sandboxed app.

Looking on my Mac I see that FaceTime has two scheduled job plists in there you can probably use as an example.

Comment: But there is no LaunchAgents directory in the containers. Whether I have to create it by own ?

Comment: Once you are sandboxed then most of the [path finding APIs should give you the proper relative paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html). For example if you use [NSHomeDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory) it will place you in the container for the app. Then you can just copy in or create your plist.

Comment: I created the directory and put the plist there. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Did you create the LaunchAgents folder in the Containers directory or inside the Library folder of your application's container?

Comment: I created in this path: /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.sample.example/Data/Library/LaunchAgents/schedule.plist